# "connect ECONNREFUSED" with phonegap

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I'm trying to build a new phonegap project. When I type the command "phonegap build android",on  a windows console, I have this message :

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment
[phonegap] PhoneGap/Build Login
[phonegap] Sign up at build.phonegap.com
 [warning] GitHub accounts are unsupported
  [prompt] enter username: GCorbel
  [prompt] enter password:
   [error] connect ECONNREFUSED
```

I'm behind a proxy. I added my proxy to node like this :

```
npm config set https-proxy http://proxyname:8080
```

It works when I do a command like `npm install ...`.

phonegap is trying to connect "build.phonegap.com" directly, without to pass by the proxy.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following command to solve this issue

```
npm config set proxy "h t t p://domain \ username:password@servername:port/"
npm config set h t t p s-proxy "h t t p:// domain \ username:password@servername:port/" 
npm config set registry h t t p://registry.npmjs.org/
```