# ECONNREFUSED error when trying to download cordova plugins

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

So, I'm trying to download a cordova plugin to my newly created project (which was created using CLI). Next, I'd like to add file support to it. So I do this :

> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file

I get this output :

> Fetching plugin from "org.apache.cordova.file"...
>
> Can't fetch : ECONNREFUSED

This looks like a nodeJS error (I've looked at many links) but I'm not able to make head/ toe of it, so any guidance might be helpful.
[There's someone who's already asked for why this happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096653/connect-econnrefused-with-phonegap), but it looks like there's no response to it, so reposting :)

My cordova version  is  : 3.1.0 and I'm under an authenticated proxy. **And yes, I've added the related nodeJS settings for proxy and stuff.**

**Verbose mode (added a -d to the command)**

> Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "org.apache.cordova.file" Fetching
>
> > plugin from "org.apache.cordova.file"... Error: Error fetching plugin:
> >     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
> >         at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\plugin.js:94:41 at _rejected (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
> >         at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
> >         at Promise.when (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\no
> >     de_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
> >         at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
> >     _modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
> >         at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
> >         at flush (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
> >         at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

Comment: Can you try running it with `-d` to see if there is any more debug info?

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes @VladStirbu I am behind a proxy

Comment: @MBillau I'll update the question with the verbose mode output in a while. I'm not at my PC yet.

Comment: added the extras in the question @MBillau

Comment: Hmmm, Cordova CLI should use your npm-proxy settings if they were set up correctly, see here: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-cli.git;h=1148e6f
Also, the bottom of the cli-readme here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli
Did you set both `https-proxy` and `proxy` npm config variables?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm facing the same issue and I still cannot get plugins to install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the same error. I had previously set the 'proxy' and 'http-proxy' config settings for npm, but I also needed to set 'https-proxy'.

Once I set that, it worked perfectly.

```
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy:port
```

Comment: do you have any idea to disable plug-in download from the internet. I loose my internet connection many times at the same day and cordova gives me errors when compiling because I am offline.